# Почему не отображается содержимое сервера в собранном проекте?

Tags: node.js, webpack, angular

Я только начал работать с Angular и Webpack, и после своей первой сборки с помощью `npm run build` столкнулся с проблемой. После запуска команды `webpack-dev-server --hot --open` или открытия собранного проекта, не отображается содержимое сервера. Только текст **Loading..** внутри тега селектора `<app></app>`, и больше ничего.

Что выходит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А содержимого сервера, которое вызывается этим тегом - нет. При запуске команды `webpack-dev-server` выходит следующая ошибка:

**Ошибка**

```
Uncaught Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings.
at assertArrayOfStrings (compiler.js:5951)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:21309)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentMetadata (compiler.js:21955)
at eval (compiler.js:21614)
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:21614)
at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:27661)
at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:27642)
at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:27602)
at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:158)
```

В чём проблема? Не могу понять. Спасибо за любую вашу помощь.

Comment: если, я правильно понимаю, то Вам, на данном этапе, необходимо собирать проект в dev-режиме, а команда `npm run build`?, тоже, по идее - собирает проект в прод-режиме

Comment: а зачем ты вовсе ранишь команду `webpack-dev-server` если есть `ng serve`?